# Make sure all four options on both side clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
  var pet = $("structureValue").val() == "Pet";
 var Color = $("button").on("click",function(){
  var color =$("#color");
  var roof  =  $("#structureValue").val() ==  "Roof";
  var building =$("#structureValue").val() ==  "Building";
  var colorId=$(color).val();
 if(colorId == "a" &&  roof){
  $("#build").css("color", "grey")
 }else if(colorId == "b" && roof){
  $("#build").css("color", "green")
 }else if(colorId == "c" && roof){
  $("#build").css("color", "orange")
 }else if(colorId == "d" && roof){
  $("#build").css("color", "yellow")
 }else if(colorId == "a" && building){
  $("#building").css("background", "grey")
 }else if(colorId == "b" && building){
  $("#building").css("background", "green")
 }else if(colorId == "c" && building){
  $("#building").css("background", "orange")
 }else if(colorId == "d" && building){
  $("#building").css("background", "yellow")
 }
});

 /*--------------------Function------------------*/
 $("#structureValue ").on("click",function(){
   $("#structureValue").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
  if(val == "Environment"){
 $("#color").html("<option  value='a'>Mountain</option><option value='b'>Lakeside</option><option value='c'>Beach</option><option value='d'>Island</option>");
 }else if(val == "Pet"){
$("#color").html("<option  value='a'>Squire</option><option value='b'>Chinchilla</option><option value='c'>Dinosaur</option><option value='d'>Dog</option>");
 }else if (val == "Roof","Building"){
 $("#color").html("<option value='a'>Gray</option><option value='b'>Green</option><option value='c'>Orange</option><option value='d'>Yellow</option>")}
});
});
  $("#firstButton").on("click", function(){
     var color =$("#color");
        var colorId=$(color).val();
 if($("#structureValue").val() ==  "Roof" ){
  $("#build").css({"width":"0",
   "height":"0","border-left":" 250px solid transparent","border-right":" 250px solid transparent",
   "border-bottom":" 350px solid ","background":"none", Color });
 }else if($("#structureValue").val() ==  "Building"){
  $("#building").css({"width":"500px",
   "height":"300px",Color })
 }else if($("#structureValue").val() == "Environment" &&  colorId == "a"){
      $("body").css({"background":"url('https://tpwd.texas.gov/state-parks/franklin-mountains/gallery/franklin-mnt_panorama1.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed",
  "-webkit-background-size": "cover","-moz-background-size":"cover","-o-background-size": "cover","background-size":"cover","background-size":"100% 100%"});
 }else if($("#structureValue").val() == "Environment" &&  colorId == "b"){
      $("body").css({"background":"url('https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/218873/Autumn-By-The-Lake.png')no-repeat center center fixed",
  "-webkit-background-size": "cover","-moz-background-size":"cover","-o-background-size": "cover","background-size":"cover","background-size":"100% 100%"});
 }else if($("#structureValue").val() == "Environment" &&  colorId == "c"){
     $("body").css({"background":"url('http://travel.home.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/travel/fullset/2014/12/3/top-10-caribbean-beaches-eagle-beach-aruba.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.966.725.suffix/1491584555480.jpeg')no-repeat center center fixed",
  "-webkit-background-size": "cover","-moz-background-size":"cover","-o-background-size": "cover","background-size":"cover","background-size":"100% 100%"});
 }else if($("#structureValue").val() == "Environment" &&  colorId == "d"){
     $("body").css({"background":"url('http://www.jeremyrobinsononline.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/White_Island_New_Zealand.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed",
  "-webkit-background-size": "cover","-moz-background-size":"cover","-o-background-size": "cover","background-size":"cover","background-size":"100% 100%"});

 }else if($("#structureValue").val() == "Pet" &&  colorId == "a"){
      $("#pet").empty().append("<img class='secert' src='https://media.giphy.com/media/eGOorb2NowXny/giphy.gif'></img>");
 }else if($("#structureValue").val() == "Pet" &&  colorId == "b"){
      $("#pet").empty().append("<img class='secert' src='https://assets.horsenation.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/1379338067174322.gif'></img>");
 }else if($("#structureValue").val() == "Pet" &&  colorId == "c"){
     $("#pet").empty().append("<img class='secert' src='https://i0.wp.com/media.giphy.com/media/TfFbA8xkrIymk/giphy.gif?resize=500%2C281&ssl=1'></img>");
 }else if($("#structureValue").val() == "Pet" &&  colorId == "d"){
     $("#pet").empty().append("<img class='secert' src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/barkpost-assets/50+GIFs/17.gif'></img>");
 }
});

$("#firstButton").click(function(){
    if($("#structureValue").val() == "Environment" && "Building" && "Roof" && "Pet"  ){
     $("#suprise").css("visibility","visible");

    }else{
     console.log("wrong")
    }
});
$("#suprise").click(function(){
 $("#glide").addClass("glide");
 setTimeout(function(){ $(".secert").css("visibility","visible");
}, 4500);
 setTimeout(function(){
   location.reload();
  }, 8500);
})
```

```css
body{background-color: green;

  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
background-size: 100% 100%
}
img{
 max-width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
}
#wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;

}
#build,#building,#doors,#windows{
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.glide{
 animation-name:glide;
 animation-duration:8.5s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction:normal;
 position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glide {
    0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
    15%  { left:0; top:50%;}
    25%  {left:80%; top:50%;}
    35%  {left:80%; top:0;}
    40%  { left:35%; top:0%;}
    75% { left:35%; top:15%;}
    100% { left:35%; top:15%;}

}

#suprise{
    visibility:hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.secert{
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="build a house.css">
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="cf">
 <div id="wrapper">
      <h1>What animal is in your house?</h1>
      Create a home vision
      <select id="structureValue">
         <option value="z">please select</option>
         <option value="Roof" name="structure">Roof</option>
         <option value="Building" name="structure">Building</option>
         <option  value="Environment" name="structure">Environment</option>
         <option   value="Pet" name="structure">Pet</option>
      </select>
      Choose the details
       <select id="color">
         <option value="z">please select</option>
         <option value="a">Gray</option>
         <option value="b">Green</option>
         <option value="c">Orange</option>
         <option value="d">Yellow</option>
      </select>
      <button id="firstButton">Click Me</button>
      <br>
       <button id="suprise">What's in my house</button>
   <div id="glide">
      <div id="build">
        
      </div>
      <div id="building">
           <div id="pet"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
     
<script type="text/javascript" src="build a house.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$("#suprise").click(function() {
  $("#glide").addClass("glide");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".secert").css("visibility", "visible");
  }, 4500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 8500);
})
$("#firstButton").click(function() {
  if ($("#structureValue").val() === "Environment" && "Building" && "Roof" && "Pet") {
    $("#suprise").css("visibility", "visible");
  }
});
```

```css
#suprise {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.secert {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="structureValue">
   <option value="Roof" name="structure">Roof</option>
   <option value="Building" name="structure">Building</option>
   <option  value="Environment" name="structure">Environment</option>
   <option   value="Pet" name="structure">Pet</option>
</select>
<select id="color">
   <option value="a">Gray</option>
   <option value="b">Green</option>
   <option value="c">Orange</option>
   <option value="d">Yellow</option>
</select>
<button id="firstButton">Click Me</button>
<br>
<button id="suprise">What's in my house</button>
<div id="glide">
  <div id="build"></div>
  <div id="building">
    <div id="pet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some odd reason, I can't get this function to work.

I want each option clicked then I want my function to turn my invisible div to visible.

How can I make sure all choices are made before the function run.

At the moment when I click Environment, it shows the #surprise  visible.

I want to have to click all values for it to show #surprise visible.

Comment: Example

Example roof--- green --- click                                                             

building--- green --- click                                                         

pet--- green --- click                                                                                  
    
Environment --- green --- click

Comment: sorry It's there now

Comment: So you want that both select-box need to be selected first and then when button is clicked div need to be visible. Am i right? if yse then you have to add an empty value option like `please select` in both select-box and then you can go for it

Comment: Yes but after they have made a choice for each option. as in the first option is roof(first select) then they will pick the color (second select) then click. After that do it for the other 3 choices. then show visible.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#firstButton').click(function(){
    $('#surpise').css("visibility",'visible');
});
```

Comment: I want all of the options clicked first . It needs to be a if Statement.

Example 
roof --- green  then click
pet--- green then click
building---- green then click
environment --- green then click
 then show visibility

Comment: everything time someone clicks Click Me you're going to have to store the option value in an array. Then check if the array contains all the available option values. if they do then do the visibility visible

Answer (score 0):

Kinda unsure what it is you want, but try this.

```
var structure = ["Environment", "Building", "Roof", "Pet"];
var clickedElements = []
$("#firstButton").click(function() {
  if (structure.indexOf($("#structureValue").val()) > -1) {
    if (clickedElements.length == structure.length) {
      $("#suprise").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else {
      if (clickedElements.indexOf($("#structureValue").val()) == -1) {
        clickedElements.push($("#structureValue").val())
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#suprise").click(function() {
  $("#glide").addClass("glide");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".secert").css("visibility", "visible");
  }, 4500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 8500);
})
var structure = ["Environment", "Building", "Roof", "Pet"];
var clickedElements = []
$("#firstButton").click(function() {
  if (structure.indexOf($("#structureValue").val()) > -1) {
    if (clickedElements.length == structure.length) {
      $("#suprise").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else {
      if (clickedElements.indexOf($("#structureValue").val()) == -1) {
        clickedElements.push($("#structureValue").val())
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#suprise {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.secert {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="structureValue">
         <option value="Roof" name="structure">Roof</option>
         <option value="Building" name="structure">Building</option>
         <option  value="Environment" name="structure">Environment</option>
         <option   value="Pet" name="structure">Pet</option>
      </select>
<select id="color">
         <option value="a">Gray</option>
         <option value="b">Green</option>
         <option value="c">Orange</option>
         <option value="d">Yellow</option>
      </select>
<button id="firstButton">Click Me</button>
<br>
<button id="suprise">What's in my house</button>
<div id="glide">
  <div id="build">

  </div>
  <div id="building">
    <div id="pet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I can only send over some of my code so it looks kinda off.
The issue I'm having is when I enter the if statement you see above, it's not checking all &&.  the div turns visible  after  Environment button is clicked. I want  the div to  be visible after all four  have been clicked.

 Example
 roof --- green then click pet--- green then click building---- green then click environment --- green then click then show visibility –

Comment: @Ace did you try the demo in the example i made?

Comment: @Ace then try clarify it better, that does not work as you want. Since i have to click all elements to make the div show

Comment: I just fully uploaded it

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, I made a snippet for you. This will show the `div` when you select all the values from **`#structureValue`** select

```js
var pet = $("structureValue").val() == "Pet";
var Color = $("button").on("click", function() {
  var color = $("#color");
  var roof = $("#structureValue").val() == "Roof";
  var building = $("#structureValue").val() == "Building";
  var colorId = $(color).val();
  if (colorId == "a" && roof) {
    $("#build").css("color", "grey")
  } else if (colorId == "b" && roof) {
    $("#build").css("color", "green")
  } else if (colorId == "c" && roof) {
    $("#build").css("color", "orange")
  } else if (colorId == "d" && roof) {
    $("#build").css("color", "yellow")
  } else if (colorId == "a" && building) {
    $("#building").css("background", "grey")
  } else if (colorId == "b" && building) {
    $("#building").css("background", "green")
  } else if (colorId == "c" && building) {
    $("#building").css("background", "orange")
  } else if (colorId == "d" && building) {
    $("#building").css("background", "yellow")
  }
});

/*--------------------Function------------------*/
$("#structureValue ").on("click", function() {
  $("#structureValue").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "Environment") {
      $("#color").html("<option  value='a'>Mountain</option><option value='b'>Lakeside</option><option value='c'>Beach</option><option value='d'>Island</option>");
    } else if (val == "Pet") {
      $("#color").html("<option  value='a'>Squire</option><option value='b'>Chinchilla</option><option value='c'>Dinosaur</option><option value='d'>Dog</option>");
    } else if (val == "Roof", "Building") {
      $("#color").html("<option value='a'>Gray</option><option value='b'>Green</option><option value='c'>Orange</option><option value='d'>Yellow</option>")
    }
  });
});
$("#firstButton").on("click", function() {
  var color = $("#color");
  var colorId = $(color).val();
  if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Roof") {
    $("#build").css({
      "width": "0",
      "height": "0",
      "border-left": " 250px solid transparent",
      "border-right": " 250px solid transparent",
      "border-bottom": " 350px solid ",
      "background": "none",
      Color
    });
  } else if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Building") {
    $("#building").css({
      "width": "500px",
      "height": "300px",
      Color
    })
  } else if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Environment" && colorId == "a") {
    $("body").css({
      "background": "url('https://tpwd.texas.gov/state-parks/franklin-mountains/gallery/franklin-mnt_panorama1.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed",
      "-webkit-background-size": "cover",
      "-moz-background-size": "cover",
      "-o-background-size": "cover",
      "background-size": "cover",
      "background-size": "100% 100%"
    });
  } else if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Environment" && colorId == "b") {
    $("body").css({
      "background": "url('https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/218873/Autumn-By-The-Lake.png')no-repeat center center fixed",
      "-webkit-background-size": "cover",
      "-moz-background-size": "cover",
      "-o-background-size": "cover",
      "background-size": "cover",
      "background-size": "100% 100%"
    });
  } else if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Environment" && colorId == "c") {
    $("body").css({
      "background": "url('http://travel.home.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/travel/fullset/2014/12/3/top-10-caribbean-beaches-eagle-beach-aruba.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.966.725.suffix/1491584555480.jpeg')no-repeat center center fixed",
      "-webkit-background-size": "cover",
      "-moz-background-size": "cover",
      "-o-background-size": "cover",
      "background-size": "cover",
      "background-size": "100% 100%"
    });
  } else if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Environment" && colorId == "d") {
    $("body").css({
      "background": "url('http://www.jeremyrobinsononline.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/White_Island_New_Zealand.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed",
      "-webkit-background-size": "cover",
      "-moz-background-size": "cover",
      "-o-background-size": "cover",
      "background-size": "cover",
      "background-size": "100% 100%"
    });

  } else if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Pet" && colorId == "a") {
    $("#pet").empty().append("<img class='secert' src='https://media.giphy.com/media/eGOorb2NowXny/giphy.gif'></img>");
  } else if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Pet" && colorId == "b") {
    $("#pet").empty().append("<img class='secert' src='https://assets.horsenation.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/1379338067174322.gif'></img>");
  } else if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Pet" && colorId == "c") {
    $("#pet").empty().append("<img class='secert' src='https://i0.wp.com/media.giphy.com/media/TfFbA8xkrIymk/giphy.gif?resize=500%2C281&ssl=1'></img>");
  } else if ($("#structureValue").val() == "Pet" && colorId == "d") {
    $("#pet").empty().append("<img class='secert' src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/barkpost-assets/50+GIFs/17.gif'></img>");
  }
});



var arrOne = [];
var arrTwo = [];
var arrOneSelected = [];
var arrTwoSelected = [];
$("#structureValue option").each(function() {
  arrOne.push($(this).html());
});
$("#color option").each(function() {
  arrTwo.push($(this).html());
});

//console.log(arrOne.slice(1),arrTwo.slice(1));
$('#structureValue').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).val() != "z"){
    arrOneSelected.push($(this).val());
  }
})
$("#firstButton").click(function() {
  if (arrOneSelected.length == (arrOne.length -1)) {
    $("#suprise").css("visibility", "visible");

  } else {
    console.log("wrong")
  }
});


$("#suprise").click(function() {
  $("#glide").addClass("glide");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".secert").css("visibility", "visible");
  }, 4500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 8500);
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#build,
#building,
#doors,
#windows {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

.glide {
  animation-name: glide;
  animation-duration: 8.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glide {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  15% {
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
  }
  25% {
    left: 80%;
    top: 50%;
  }
  35% {
    left: 80%;
    top: 0;
  }
  40% {
    left: 35%;
    top: 0%;
  }
  75% {
    left: 35%;
    top: 15%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 35%;
    top: 15%;
  }
}

#suprise {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.secert {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="build a house.css">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="cf">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>What animal is in your house?</h1>
    Create a home vision
    <select id="structureValue">
         <option value="z">please select</option>
         <option value="Roof" name="structure">Roof</option>
         <option value="Building" name="structure">Building</option>
         <option  value="Environment" name="structure">Environment</option>
         <option   value="Pet" name="structure">Pet</option>
      </select> Choose the details
    <select id="color">
         <option value="z">please select</option>
         <option value="a">Gray</option>
         <option value="b">Green</option>
         <option value="c">Orange</option>
         <option value="d">Yellow</option>
      </select>
    <button id="firstButton">Click Me</button>
    <br>
    <button id="suprise">What's in my house</button>
    <div id="glide">
      <div id="build">

      </div>
      <div id="building">
        <div id="pet"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="build a house.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```